# Prevent application picker when opening app with URL

Tags: android, url

Is there a way to prevent the application picker from opening when trying to open an application using an URL? My intent filter currently looks like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="SITE_URL" android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>
```

This brings up the application picker when trying to access the specific URL, but is there some other way to do this that opens the application right away?

Comment: can you use a custom scheme ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using the callback URL from an API to open the app, and the API requires me to use https.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, application picker is call for a specific scheme and "browser" listen https.